# Informatica is not populating time in a timestamp column

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am populating a timestamp value from a column with timestamp datatype to a column with timestamp datatype using Informatica. My source qualifier query is getting the correct output but when I am loading to target, its loading as 12:00:00 time for all the records instead of the time from the source.

Comment: See [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Could you advise what the source and targets are? E.g. csv to oracle date column. Also, trace the port from source to target checking any data type / scale of all the ports this field moves through to see if this changes at all. A lot of applications, such as excel, store datetime in a number where the whole digits represent the date and the fractional digits represent the time so if the fractions get truncated, only the date goes through and you land up with a time of 00:00:00 which is 12.

Answer (score 0):

An easy analysis for you to do is on the workflow, right click the session task and select edit. Click on the config tab and then set the override tracing value to verbose data.

Rerun the mapping and you can see what the date value is set to at each transformation it passes through.

Identify exactly which transformation is the one where date becomes day without time and then troubleshoot only that one.

2 caveats... dont do this on production and make sure you change the override tracing back when you're done so that it doesnt find its way into production

Further steps on setting override tracing can be seen in this kb https://kb.informatica.com/howto/6/Pages/_0/160860.aspx